# Postgres client not queryable through AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda

I'm trying to connect to postgres through nodejs code.
The nodejs-code is shown below.

```js
const pg = require("pg");


let client;
async function connect () {
  if (client) return client
  client = new pg.Client({
    user             : "xxx",
    password         : "xxx",
    host             : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    port             : "xxxx",
    application_name : "AWS-Lambda",
    database         : "xxx"
  });
  await client.connect()
  return client;
}

async function execute (query, values) {
  if (!client) throw ('CLIENT NOT CONNECTED');
  return await client.query({ text: query, values }); 
}

async function close () {
  if (!client) return false
  await client.end();
  client = undefined;
  return true;
}
```

facing the below error sometimes, **which is unable to reproduce**

```
Error: Client was closed and is not queryable
at process.nextTick (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:535:25)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

I tried searching at all the places for this, but unable to find the correct solution for this.
And unable to reproduce this to investigate this.

Could anyone help me cracking this.

Comment: Actually this is happened within AWS-lambda, which can create a concurrencies for balancing the load. So I'm unable to get the situation when this error happened, like for every request I'm opening the connection and using the database queries and closing the connection.
So any ideas on how this error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Aws recommends you to create a database proxy while connecting to RDS via Lambda .
[Check this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-database.html)  .